# Diacritic connecting c and t

Tags: graphemics

What is the name and use of the extra bow on the letter c in *Doctrine*? Diacritic or calligraphic decoration, or misprint?

[image]

---

Edit: With the name given in the comments, I found an existing good answer here:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25118/is-there-any-significance-in-little-curls-joining-the-st-and-ct-in-old-books

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a diacritic, it is a ligature. These are probably more common in older typesetting.

The same thing can be done with the sequence `<st>` as with `<ct>`.

Comment: BTW the combination is a ligature. What is the name of that specific diacritic, if it even has a name?

Comment: @user6726 what diacritic are you referring to? There isn't one in the rendition of "ct" up there; it's only a graphical variation.

Comment: The "hook" is a frequent diacritic between *t* and certain consonants in older manuscripts. I don't care if you don't like the name "diacritic": my question is what that character is called. Do you have a reason to not call it a diacritic? For example, what do you call "cedilla", "tilde" and so on?

Comment: @user6726 The name of the character is, or would be, "C-T ligature". Even if what you're looking for existed, it would be considered a typographical term like "serif", "swash", etc. not a diacritic.

Answer (score 4):

I just wanted to add a brief comment re: the name of the connecting element in question.

I personally haven't seen any standardised term for it. Sometimes it is referred to as **a bow** or **a loop** (e.g. the Chicago Manual of Style, 17th ed.). Descriptively, it is **a semicircular stroke** above *ct*.

I'm not quite sure why - perhaps @Cerberus or someone else could corroborate this - but I think it is so because it would be rather superfluous. The most common way to refer to ct is either the ct-ligature or ligatured ct, which already implies presence/use of the connecting symbol, so really there is no need to have a special term for it.

see below, for instance, a screenshot from [Delorez 2006](https://www.cambridge.org/gb/academic/subjects/literature/anglo-saxon-and-medieval-literature/palaeography-gothic-manuscript-books-twelfth-early-sixteenth-century?) *The Palaeography of Gothic manuscript books: From the twelfth to the early sixteenth century*:

[image]

Comment: This should be the accepted answer